# Plotting multiple locations on map by fetching latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, plot

I am working on a script to plot multiple locations on a map using google maps.
I took the reference of [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-API-V3-Add-multiple-markers-with-InfoWindow-to-Google-Map.aspx) script which has a static json of locations to plot.
As I needed to get the lat lng of locations first I referred [this](https://gist.github.com/BastinRobin/7463602) gist.
I tried merging the 2 scripts to get a plotting for multiple but,I am facing an issue in the loop. The function currently plots only the last location and
for the first 2 it does not call the `getLocation` function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

 var markers = [
 {
    "title": 'Juhu Beach',
    "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favourite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
    "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
},
{
    "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
    "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
}
];
window.onload = function () {
    LoadMap();
}
var json = {};
var latitude;
var longitude;
var getLocation =  function(address,callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      json = {
        'lat':latitude,
        'lng':longitude
      }
      if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback(json);
      }
    }
  });
}

function LoadMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    //Create and open InfoWindow.
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var data;
    var myLatlng;
    var marker;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        data = markers[i];
        console.log('object',data.description);
        getLocation(data.description,function(result){               
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.lat, result.lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
        });
            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        })

    }
}
```

I am unable to figure where the callback is breaking for first 2 loops.Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have a working version. If you bound your latitude and longitude (you get from geocode) and then fit those with the viewport using fitBound. Please see the working version below:

```
var markers = [
{
   "title": 'Juhu Beach',
   "description": 'New York, NY'
},
{
    "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
    "description": 'Delhi, In'
},
{
    "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
    "description": 'Oslo, NO'
}
];


window.onload = function () {
    LoadMap();
}
var json = {};
var latitude;
var longitude;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  // Added this line

var getLocation =  function(address,callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      json = {
        'lat':latitude,
        'lng':longitude
      }
      if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback(json);
      }
    }
  });
}

function LoadMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    //Create and open InfoWindow.
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var data;
    var myLatlng;
    var marker;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        data = markers[i];
        console.log('object',data.description);
        getLocation(data.description,function(result){
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result.lat, result.lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition()); // Added this line
        map.fitBounds(bounds); // Added this line
            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to fetch the lat long dynamically that is why I need the `getLocation` function which will return the lat long.Hence I have removed the lat and long parameters from the JSON.

Comment: I have edited my answer by keeping your getLocation function. Please check now.

Comment: Your solution works,but there is an issue,the marker function I have used to mark the location is called after the locations are plotted and hence it takes the last locations description and applies it to all. So all locations have same value as description on click. How to fix this